# Exporting JS code from NodeJS HTML files to JS files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, import, export

I am new to Nodejs and having trouble when trying to **export my js code which exists in HTML files to more js files** for less redundancy in code (same js code in two HTML files):

I exported the js code from both HTML files to js a file (js_code_file.js for example) and tried using `<script src="js_code_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in the header of the HTML file in order to import the file, and it did not work.

Is it because of Nodejs? and if it is - is there a way to "require" these files somehow?

Comment: Why did it not work? Did you get errors? Also, what is your JS code doing? And how is NodeJS linked to this? Can you please show us the (relevant) code you're trying to export, and also the (relevant) HTML?

Comment: Nodejs for handling get requests from user and providing the correct html file from the two. the JS code is only function definitions to be used by, for example, button's "onclick" in the html file.

Comment: Okay, I see. Can you please add some of your JavaScript from the external .js file, and also some relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="js_code_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Looking at the src attribute, js_code_file.js has to be in the same path as the .html file referencing it; that is, it has to literally be in the same folder.  So make sure that is the case, otherwise, update your question with any errors you might be receiving.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same html folder as the html files. The thing is I am not getting any errors. The js file contains functions def's only and no other code. So the html file has ```<input type="submit" class="btn-primary" value="Submit Selections" onclick="submit_filters()">``` for example, and submit_filters function is in the js file. When I hit this button nothing happens.

Comment: I'd have to see the code then; it sounds like those function definitions aren't publicly accessible.  Are they wrapped in an outer function?

Comment: I figured it out. In the index.js file which i run from the cmd with ```node index.js```, I needed to include a line for requiring the folder which I am using for the html and js files: ```app.use('/html', express.static('html'));```